# Using Foreach to loop through children with a delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my current project I'm trying to iterate through all the children of a parent and activate a component on each child with a time delay after each. Currently unity stops responding when this method is called, im guessing that nesting while loops in foreach loops is a bad idea? How should i be approaching this problem, I'm pretty stumped.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, this is what I'm currently doing (with little success):

```
float simpleTimer;

void Update()
{
    simpleTimer += Time.deltaTime;
}
public void ReelIn()
{
    foreach (Transform child in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
    {
        simpleTimer = 0;
        while (simpleTimer < 0.5f)
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to do that.

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(ReelIn());
}

private IEnumerator ReelIn()
{
    foreach (Transform child in gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I hadn't played around with Coroutines yet. Thanks heaps for your help!